# ReSharper 6: Go To Derived Symbols - how to Include Library Types?

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0, code-navigation

I remember that in R# 5 when you hit alt-end (go to inheritor), there was a list of inheritors which included library types. And types from current solution were bold.

In version 6 I'm not able to see derived types in libraries, and I can't find an option to enable this. Is it possible?

Comment: I had the exact same problem a couple of weeks ago, and [reported it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-287632) Now I can't reproduce it anymore. It has *possibly* gone away after upgrading to the initial [6.1.1 early build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.1.1+Nightly+Builds) but I'm not really sure. You might try install it if you're fine with pre-release builds.

Comment: Thank you! Early build fixed the problem! Спасибо :)